# Is it legal to begin an x64 function with a single-byte instruction?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64

According to masm's macamd64.inc, `rex_push_reg`,

> ...rex_push_reg must be used in lieu of push_reg when it appears as
>   the first instruction in a function, as the calling standard dictates
>   that functions must not begin with a single byte instruction.

I wasn't able to find any documentation expressing this, however. Is this true? Where is it documented? Why is this the case?

Comment: [MSDN : *"This should be used if the push is the first instruction in the function to ensure that the function is hot-patchable"*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235217.aspx). [Freiks Weblog: "*I don’t think there’s anything that prevents you from breaking these particular rules*"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/freik/2006/03/07/what-does-hot-patchability-mean-and-what-is-it-for/).

Comment: @rkhb Those links are very informative, are you going to write an answer?

Comment: @MargaretBloom: No, I've never handled hot patchability. The chance to write crap is too big.

Comment: Hot-patching is useful in a server-style app that cannot reasonably be stopped and restarted to install an update.  So you can deploy the update *while* the code is executing.  That is tricky if you modify the function at the very moment it is executing of course.  The 2 bytes are necessary to patch in a short JMP to the modified code.  Can't be 1 byte, big bummer if it resumes executing at offset 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operative portion of this claim seems to be "the calling standard"—*which* calling standard? The joke may be an old one, but it remains apt: the great thing about standards is there are so many to choose from.

In this case, since you're speaking of MASM, we can assume that the target platform is Windows, so the [Windows 64-bit calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions) would be assumed, rather than something in the official AMD64 specification. However, like you, I can't find anything there that speaks to this requirement.

However, I *think* what this comment is referring to is Microsoft's internal standard designed to allow hot patching of system binaries. By "hot patching" is meant the ability to dynamically patch binaries in memory—*e.g.* to apply a system update—without the need to restart.

The minimum requirement for this to work is that there is room for a 2-byte short `JMP` instruction to be patched in at the beginning of every function. (Note that a short jump only allows execution to be passed anywhere from −128 to +127 bytes from the current instruction pointer, but that's enough to branch to a *long* jump, which then branches to the patched function provided by the update. In practice, the long jump instruction is patched into the padding between functions.)

Therefore, a function cannot begin with a 1-byte instruction because then a hot patch could potentially result in the instruction pointer pointing into the *middle* of an instruction. (Think about multi-threading race conditions.) So the rule is, if you want to begin a function with a prologue instruction like `PUSH RBP` that would normally be only 1 byte, you need to add a 1-byte REX prefix. This unnecessary REX prefix is ignored by the CPU and functions essentially as a 1-byte NOP.

In 32-bit builds, hot patching was provided for by the 2-byte instruction `MOV EDI, EDI`. This copies the `EDI` register to itself without affecting flags, so it is effectively a NOP.

For 32-bit builds, you have to specifically pass the [`/hotpatch` switch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173507.aspx) to the compiler to have it insert this instruction. However, on 64-bit builds, the compiler always acts as if `/hotpatch` has been specified, so this requirement that the first instruction be 2 bytes in length effectively becomes part of the platform standard.

So, why make this complicated rule instead of just having the compiler insert a 2-byte NOP at the beginning of every function, like is done in 32-bit builds? Well, I can't say for certain, but I can speculate. One problem is that `MOV EDI, EDI` is *not* a NOP on x64 because it implicitly zeroes the upper 32-bits of the `RDI` register. You'd have to choose a different instruction as the NOP, and once you've done that, you might as well rethink the whole business. Second, there is a (slight) performance cost you pay for having that NOP there, and since *most* instructions in long mode are at least 2 bytes long, it hardly seems worth it to require a pointless NOP instruction when the instruction that would normally be there is sufficient with only a few exceptions.

Comment: Aha, makes sense that MS is referring to their internal convention. Thank you.

Comment: And I see that rkhb has confirmed the correctness of my answer with the links he dug up and posted in a comment. Getting scooped is the price I pay for stopping to make a cup of tea while writing this. :-)